# How to do string concatenation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to check user input before displaying the correct HTML element.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var additem = '<div><div class="itesm">' +
'<h1>'+itemname+'</h1>';
if(itype == 'edit'){
 additem .= '<div><input id="itemdis" value="'+itemdis+'"></div>';
}else{
 additem .= 'Good item';
}
 additem .= '</div>';
$('showitem').html(additem);
</script>
```

I always do something like this in PHP, but I can't figure out how to do it in javaScript.

Can anyone tell me how to concatenate the strings together so that my example works?

Comment: Put `+` instead of `.`  Javascript uses `+` operator as concatenation...

Comment: @YashParekh i thing i found this `additem.concat(additem1, additem2);` and it worked

Comment: You can use es6 template strings : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Your line 2 + 3 are doing exactly what you want to know. This is easy to Google.

Comment: @PhilipJems You said about operator and `concat()` is a function. After all working things will be better than nothing. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var itype = 'edit';
var additem = '<div><div class="itesm"><h1>ABC</h1>';
if(itype == 'edit'){
 additem += '<div><input id="itemdis" value="ABC"></div>';
}else{
 additem += 'Good item';
}
 additem += '</div>';
$('div').html(additem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="showtime"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` instead of `.`, check snippet below..

```js
var itemname = "itemname",
    itemdis = "itemdis",
    itype = "edit";

var additem = '<div><div class="itesm">' +
'<h1>'+itemname+'</h1>';
if(itype == 'edit'){
 additem += '<div><input id="itemdis" value="'+itemdis+'"></div>';
}else{
 additem += 'Good item';
}
 additem += '</div>';
document.getElementById('showitem').innerHTML =  additem;
```

```html
<div id="showitem"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
<script>
var additem = '<div><div class="itesm">' +
'<h1>'+itemname+'</h1>';
  if(itype == 'edit'){
   additem .= '<div><input id="itemdis" value="'+itemdis+'"></div>';
  }else{
   additem .= 'Good item';
  }
  additem .= '</div>';
  $('showitem').html(additem);
</script>
```

Please note javascript has `+` operator for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Some other users have already pointed out that javascript uses the `+` operator and not the `.` operator (like PHP does).

A more, full-fledged example can be found at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).

Note that this, however, will not work right when you use numbers and strings combined. As demonstrated with the following code:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
console.log('result is ' + a + b);
```

The previous code will, unlike expected, print "result is 120".

There is another, well-known, way to concat strings, however. This works by using the .concat method like so:

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

Interestingly you could also convert the strings to an array and use array operations like `[push][2]` to concatenate strings.

A performance evaluation (by jsperf) can be found [here](https://jsperf.com/join-concat/2).

ps: sorry for taking so long, I forgot about this tab :)