# Convert an array of entries into HTML string

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am stuck at this point. How to get such construction:

```
 "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n"
 "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n"
 "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n"
 "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n"
 "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n"
 "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n"
```

And put it here:

```
sendText(id_callback,!!!HERE!!!,keyBoard );
```

Full code:

```
for(var i=1; i < 100; i++){
  if (expenseSheet.getRange(i, 27).getValue() == id_callback) { 
    var studentsGrade = expenseSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 25).getValues(); 
    var gradesName = expenseSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 25).getValues();
    for(var q=1; q < 10; q++){
      if (studentsGrade[0][3+q] !== "") {
      var gradesNameArray = [gradesName[0][3+q],];
      var studentsGradeArray = [studentsGrade[0][3+q],];
      var gradesMessageText = "<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"\n";
    } 
  }            
}
}         
sendText(id_callback,gradesMessageText,keyBoard );
```

Also I need to check if each `[studentsGrade[0][3+q],]` is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Generating and concatenating strings via looping over a collection of data.

**Explanation**

The reason why strings are not concatenated is that at each iteration of the loop you *redeclare* the `gradesMessageText` variable and, more importantly, [*initialize*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714434/declaring-vs-initializing-a-variable) it again, until during last iteration the variable gets assigned the data from last entry in the collection.

If you used `cost` or `let`, this will not even work, but due to a peculiar behaviour of `var`, so called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) bumps it to the top of the scope (top of the function scope in your case), making it available to be referenced later in `sendText`.

**Optimizations**

As it stands now, you script is bound to be slow (the more records, the worse it will get), because you use input / output (I/O) operations in a loop (`getRange()` -> `getValue()` chain, `getValues()` used for extracting a single row). It is best practice to do such operations in batch (i.e. use `getValues()` once and work on an in-memory array the rest of the time).

*Runnable test version:*

```js
const id_callback = 26;

const testGrades = [
 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(""),
 [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
];
const [names] = testGrades.slice(0);

const parsed = testGrades
  .filter(gradeRow => gradeRow[26] === id_callback && gradeRow.slice(4,12).every(Boolean))
  .map(gradeRow => {
    const name = names.slice(4,12);

    return gradeRow.slice(4,12).reduce((acc,cur,i) => acc += `<b>${name[i]}:</b> ${cur}\n`, "");
  });
       
console.log(parsed.join(""));
```

*Sample with services:*

```
const grades = expenseSheet.getRange(1, 1, 99, 25).getValues();
const [ names ] = grades.slice(0);

const parsed = grades
  .filter(gradeRow => gradeRow[26] === id_callback && gradeRow.slice(4,12).every(Boolean))
  .map(gradeRow => {
    const name = names.slice(4,12);

    return gradeRow.slice(4,12).reduce((acc,cur,i) => acc += `<b>${names[i]}:</b> ${cur}\n`, "");
  });

sendText(id_callback, parsed.join("") , keyBoard);
```

**References**

1. `map()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. `filter()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
3. `slice()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
4. [String concatenation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835690/how-to-do-string-concatenation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var gradesMessageText=""
for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
  if (expenseSheet.getRange(i, 27).getValue() == id_callback) { 
    var studentsGrade = expenseSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 25).getValues(); 
    var gradesName = expenseSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 25).getValues();
    for(var q=1; q < 10; q++){
      if (studentsGrade[0][3+q] !== "") {
      var gradesNameArray = [gradesName[0][3+q]];
      var studentsGradeArray = [studentsGrade[0][3+q]];
      gradesMessageText+="<b>"+gradesNameArray+":</b> "+studentsGradeArray+"<br />";
    } 
  }            
}
}         
sendText(id_callback,gradesMessageText,keyBoard );
```